# android camera driver rotate 90°

Tags: android, kernel

the project is in the sdm450 and used mmcamera architecture ,All applications are displayed vertically, but now I want the horizontal screen effect，so I have to rotate 90 degrees In the camera driver I want to change the angle 90°,in the msm8953_config.xml change the angle ，but the image is stretched. so how to change the angle in the driver or HAL,thanks

I want to know how to change the image is not stretched? thanks